# Model state is valid, but status 400 is returned

Tags: c#, validation, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to figure out what's going on with my routing. Here's the action in controller with two routes.

```
public enum AvaibleScheduleEventParticipantGroupType
{
    Teachers,
    ...
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("groups/{type}/{id?}", Order = 1)]
[Route("groups/{type}", Order = 2)]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable))]
public IEnumerable GetParticipantGroupForScheduleEvent(AvaibleScheduleEventParticipantGroupType type, Guid? id = null)
{
    var request = new ScheduleEventParticipantGroupRequest
    {
        Type = type,
        Id = id
    };
    return GettingParticipantGroupForScheduleEventService.HandleGroupRequest(request);
}
```

After some time spent on playing around with route paths, I finally found a solution that doesn't end up with message "No action was found on the controller" when I try navigating

`http://localhost:65358/api/scheduleevents/groups/teachers`

Now I'm getting `400 status` **altough I have no validation on my parameters**. Weird.
I've looked on what's happening in IIS with `Output` window and found this:

```
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=GET, Url=http://localhost:65358/api/scheduleevents/groups/teachers, Message='http://localhost:65358/api/scheduleevents/groups/teachers'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='ScheduleEvent', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Nau.Dzienniczek.Api.Areas.Schedule.Controllers.ScheduleEventController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Nau.Dzienniczek.Api.Areas.Schedule.Controllers.ScheduleEventController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'GetParticipantGroupForScheduleEvent(AvaibleScheduleEventParticipantGroupType type, Nullable`1 id)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorizationAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'type' bound to the value 'Teachers'', Operation=ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'id' bound to the value 'null'', Operation=ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: type=Teachers, id=null', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=ValidateModelAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync, Status=400 (BadRequest)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=ScheduleEventController.ExecuteAsync, Status=400 (BadRequest)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=DependencyScopeHandler.SendAsync, Status=400 (BadRequest)
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Response, Status=400 (BadRequest), Method=GET, Url=http://localhost:65358/api/scheduleevents/groups/teachers, Message='Content-type='none', content-length=unknown'
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=ScheduleEventController.Dispose
```

Look closely at the 6th line from the bottom.

`'Model state is valid. Values: type=Teachers, id=null'`

which is followed by

`Operation=ValidateModelAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync, Status=400 (BadRequest)`

So what's going on?

Url below works like a charm.

`http://localhost:65358/api/scheduleevents/groups/teachers/1e7cb4f9-8e6a-4127-9505-5fad9978ebc6`

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe webAPI can handle the conversion of enums in a route so I would change that to a string. Also, because your id parameter is optional you can condense your route.

```
[HttpGet, Route("api/scheduleevents/groups/{type}/{id:guid?}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetParticipantGroupForScheduleEvent(string type, Guid? id = null)
{
    try
    {
       var request = new ScheduleEventParticipantGroupRequest
       {
           Type = type,
           Id = id
       };

      //assuming this returns an object or list of objects
       var response = GettingParticipantGroupForScheduleEventService.HandleGroupRequest(request);

       return Ok(response);
    }
    catch
    {
       return InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

Edit: I just noticed the route you are calling is:
http://localhost:65358/api/scheduleevents/groups/teachers

Unless you are using a routePrefix on your class of api/scheduleevents you will need to add it to your route. I added it in the answer above.

Comment: I changed type to string, as you suggested, but I still get `400`.

Comment: Try changing the route as well. I think the bad request is due to the fact that you have 2 matching routes on the same endpoint. Also note the return type.

Comment: Yes, I did it too, just forgot to mention :)

Comment: In your Startup.cs file do you have this line in the Configuration mathod for allowing attribute routing? configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();